# string value does not match C# with dictionary value

Tags: c#, string, match

It is very weird but really do not know, why below two string values does not match in  code :

```
string s="TextBox1.Text= \"Hello 1"\";
public static Dictionary<string, string> dictionary =
        new Dictionary<string, string>();
    dictionary.Add("Button", "TextBox1.Text= \"Hello 1"\");
    dictionary.Add("TextBox","TextBox1.Text= \"Hello 1"\");

foreach(KeyValuePair<string,string> pair in dictionary)
{
   if(s==pair.Value.ToString())
   {
       // some code
   }
}
```

really do not know.. what could be the reason.

Comment: Does your code compile?

Comment: Make sure that pair.Value.ToString() works fine, check its value

Comment: @bit - it compiles..without error. I even tried pair.Value.ToString() still same issue.

Comment: There is a misplaced backslash at the end of every string. You have "TextBox1.Text= \"Hello 1"\"; where it should be "TextBox1.Text= \"Hello 1\"";

Comment: Is this the exact code? Because it won't even compile as it is now.

Comment: Alongside the problem with the quotes that @bit identified, you [can't declare a static variable inside a method](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/csharpfaq/archive/2004/05/11/130248.aspx).  So the static dictionary needs to be moved outside the method.

Comment: Print both strings lengths before comparing

Comment: After correcting the misplaced backslashes, and getting rid of the "public static" part, the code works fine for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are my corrections, which worked for me, see the comments with numbers

```
string s="TextBox1.Text= \"Hello 1\""; //1
    Dictionary<string, string> dictionary = //2
        new Dictionary<string, string>();
    dictionary.Add("Button", "TextBox1.Text= \"Hello 1\"");//3
    dictionary.Add("TextBox","TextBox1.Text= \"Hello 1\"");//4

foreach(KeyValuePair<string,string> pair in dictionary)
{
   if(s==pair.Value.ToString())
   {
       // some code
   }
}
```